# Scanning RSSI of BLE peripherals in background

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

**UPDATE 15/6 - 1 - ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

As per Paulw's suggestion, I changed the strategy and instead of discovering for peripherals, I connected with peripheral and it worked fine **when either peripheral or central are in foreground**. The problem occurs when:

1) I setup notifications on delegate calls.

2) Both peripheral and central are in background.

3) As I bring them closer, I see no delegate calls.

4) As soon as I bring either peripheral or central in foreground, I get `didDiscover` call and everything works fine even if I now put app in both phones in background.

In short, the central does not discover peripheral if both are in background state.
This is the code for both parts:

```
    func startAsPeripheral() {
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    }

    func startAsCentral() {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    }

}

extension BluetoothManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        LogManager.shared.log(object: "Central state update")
        LogManager.shared.log(object: central.state)
        if central.state != .poweredOn {
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Central is not powered on")
        } else {
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Central scanning for: " + self.serviceUUID.uuidString);
            self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.serviceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        self.centralManager.stopScan()
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self
        self.centralManager.connect(self.peripheral, options: nil)
        let name = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String
        LogManager.shared.log(object: "Peripheral (" + (name ?? "unknown") + "): " + RSSI.stringValue)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == self.peripheral {
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Connected.")
            peripheral.discoverServices([serviceUUID])
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        if peripheral == self.peripheral {
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Disconnected")
            self.peripheral = nil
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Central scanning for: " + self.serviceUUID.uuidString);
            self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.serviceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
        }
    }


}

extension BluetoothManager: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral( _ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        LogManager.shared.log(object: "Services: \(peripheral.services!)")
        for service in peripheral.services! {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral( _ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        LogManager.shared.log(object: "Characteristics: \(service.characteristics!)")
    }

}


extension BluetoothManager: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        switch peripheral.state {
        case .unknown:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Bluetooth Device is UNKNOWN")
        case .unsupported:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Bluetooth Device is UNSUPPORTED")
        case .unauthorized:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Bluetooth Device is UNAUTHORIZED")
        case .resetting:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Bluetooth Device is RESETTING")
        case .poweredOff:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Bluetooth Device is POWERED OFF")
        case .poweredOn:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Bluetooth Device is POWERED ON")
            let service = serviceUUID
            let myService = CBMutableService(type: service, primary: true)
            let writeCharacteristics = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: characteristricUUID, properties: .write, value: nil, permissions: .writeable)
            myService.characteristics = [writeCharacteristics]
            peripheralManager.add(myService)
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : "Spacedemic", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : [service]])
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Started Advertising")
        default:
            LogManager.shared.log(object: "Unknown State")
        }
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have an app used for contact tracing. I configure it to work as both central and peripheral, both should work in background AND foreground. This is for contact tracing, so users won't have the application in foreground state in most cases. Advertising works fine as what I have observed, both in background and foreground. The problem here is that when central is in background, it sometimes gets into `didDiscover` only one time and sometimes never. Thus if a peripheral is in range, I am unable to detect the RSSI from central or if the user moves away from the central. In contrast, when in foreground, I get frequent updates with RSSI in `didDiscover` method.
How can I solve this? Or is there a workaround to get the desired results?

Comment: Are you aware that Apple will only accept contact tracing apps from official government health agencies?  Also, if you are working on such an app as part of a government health agency I strongly suggest you adopt the Apple/Google exposure tracing framework available in iOS 13.5.  The only reliable way to continually gather RSSI in the background with Core Bluetooth is to maintain a connection to the peripheral.  This is what the Australian Government COVIDSafe app does (you can get its source code on Github)

Comment: This approach seems to have an adverse impact on other Bluetooth communications (in particular, the Apple Watch) so I have removed this app from my phone.

Comment: Thanks. As per your suggestion, I tried implementing the connect method, and I still haven't got any success. Please have a look on the edit.